# what is meaning of this piece of code?<%= some varible %>

Tags: javascript

what is meaning of this piece of code?
<%= noteNumber %> and where using?

```
<script type="text/template" id="notesTemplate">
  <div class="note col-md-5">

      <span data-note="<%= noteNumber %>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeNote"></span>
      <h1 class="well text-center"><%= title %></h1>
      <p><%= note %></p>





  </div>

</script>
```

Comment: This is code block for server side asp.net c# webforms

Comment: `type="text/template"` suggests it's a JavaScript templating library.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are in a `<script type="text/template">` tag, I think it is about some Javascript templating engine.

It is often used in Javascript templating to output a variable. See things like http://www.embeddedjs.com/